# Is it possible to take a JS var representing an element that has been appended to multiple places, and delete it using the var?

Tags: javascript, jquery

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4mLfuyx/). I have an `info` var that I can easily append to 2 places. But I'd like to also easily remove it from both places without doing something more complicated like `$("p").remove()`

I know this seems super not complicated, but in production it's harder. I'm always working with the `info` var so it'd be great if there was some way to say `info.removeInAllInstances()` or something

Comment: 1. pls post your code here, rather than send off a link (the link is fine, just add the code here too. 2. why not just give that `p` a class name and then reference it for removal?

Comment: Because jQuery clones the HTML within the loop through all the `.row` elements, `$info` will only ever refer to the last item appended - that's why you see the current behaviour. To do what you require you will have to select all the content in the DOM after the `append()` completes, ie. `$('p').remove()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan to clarify, you mean to say that when I do `$(".row").append(info)`, the `info` var is cloned in each `.append()` is that correct? and thereafter, `info` only refers to the last element?

Comment: @Kinglish I can, i'm just specifically trying to use the `info` var

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a master in JQuery, but apparentely remove() removes all instances of something. You could filter by an specific class and remove the paragraphs.

Look this example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>remove demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    background: yellow;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Hello</p>
how are
<p>you?</p>
<button>Call remove() on paragraphs</button>
 
<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).remove();
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I get it on https://api.jquery.com/remove/.

Comment: the fiddle i had used `.remove()` and it didn't work =/

Comment: try to remove by a class name, i did it and works
 info = $("<p>Enter important info</p>")
info2 = $("<p>Enter important info</p>")
// append input field into both cart & catalog
$(".row").append(info)
$(".row").append(info2)
// delete input in catalog, should delete in cart automatically, but does not, only deletes in catalog
$("p").remove()
try to do this with a classname, in this case i use a tagname.
look i'm not the specialist in jquery so i can't help you with the best way haha

Comment: yes i understand, sorry i had just mentioned in the question i'm trying specifically to use the JS `info` var that i created rather than search by class. it's ok i don't think this is possible